# NoMethodError for nil after rendering view in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have this in my view _form.erb:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :start_hour %><br>
    <%= f.select :start_hour, @select_hours.map {|value| [value, value]} %>
</div>
```

And this in edit.erb:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

And this in my controller

```
    def edit
        @user = current_user
        @employee = @user.employee
        @hour = @employee.working_hours.find(params[:id])
        @select_hours = Array.new
        for i in 0..12
          @select_hours.push("#{07+i}:00")
          @select_hours.push("#{07+i}:30")
        end
    end
```

And then my update in my controller

```
def update
    @employee = current_user.employee
    @hour = @employee.working_hours.find(params[:id])
    if @hour.update(working_hour_params)
      redirect_to employee_working_hours_path(@employee)
    else
      render :edit
    end
end
```

And here's my problem:

When I click update AND have wrong `start_hour` (custom validation, works when creating not editing), so `@hour` will not update. It renders again this view but with error that there is no method `map` for `nil` (so for `@select_hours`).

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback in your controller and set up `@select_hours` for those two actions, this way if the update fails, the value will be present, but you don't have to assign the variable twice, like:

```
before_action :set_select_hours, only: %i[edit update]
before_action :set_employee,     only: %i[edit update]
before_action :set_hour,         only: %i[edit update]

def edit; end

def update
  if @hour.update(working_hour_params)
    redirect_to employee_working_hours_path(@employee)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def set_select_hours
  @select_hours = (0..12).flat_map do |index|
    ["#{07 + index}:00", "#{07 + index}:30"]
  end
end

def set_employee
  @employee = current_user.employee
end

def set_hour
  @hour = @employee.working_hours.find(params[:id])
end
```

I think @employee can also be setted within a before callback.

I've added flat map to create and fill an array starting from the range, it's the "same" as before, just you don't need to initialize the array, use the for loop, and push the content for it.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing with `@select_hours.map {|value| [value, value]}`, but can be also done at the moment of declaring select_hours.

Comment: well i use it for selecting a time in form_for and i found this method on stackoverflow ^^ but anyway thanks for the response it worked out perfectly! And now thanks to you i will start using callbacks :)

Comment: oh right i forgot about this, sorry. Well youre right about @hour but my controller look a bit empty right now but overall thats nice as f*ck. Thanks mate for help!

Comment: Glad to help ;)